# Factorization of determinants in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, factoring

I have a situation where I have two matrices, A and B. I am trying to solve for the detriment of B given certain information. I am have gotten to the following equation using properties of detriments:

det(B)*det(A) + det(B) = 10

I was given the matrix A which was just an upper triangular matrix, thus I computed the determent by taking the product of the main diagonal, this equates to 24. It is assumed that B is the same size as A.

det(B)*24 + det(B) = 10

My question is, am I allowed to factor out the det(B) here in order to isolate it and solve what the determinant would be, is this a mathematically sound thing to do?

det(B)(24 + 1) = 10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Determinants are just numbers so you can treat them like numbers. You can even use distributivity on matrices since $A(B+C)=AB+BC$ in that case too.

Comment: Cool, thanks, this is what I thought but I couldn't remember if this was the case!